# CSS: Background-image not showing until the window scrolls (Webkit browsers)

Tags: jquery, css

I'm pretty new to StackOverflow this is the first question I will be posting.

I'm currently fixing this website: http://www.studiopetervanriet.com/site/ as a freelancer. The guys that designed it discovered a css-bug when you would visit the site with a URL like this: http://www.studiopetervanriet.com/site/#services

Because of the Hashtag in the url, the site opens up way down and for some odd reason the background image of that box won't show unless it's been cached before. 
So to trigger this bug open up Chrome/Safari, clear the browser cache and click the link(http://www.studiopetervanriet.com/site/#services)

I tried using jQuery to scroll 1px automatically on load, but because the sites needs to load longer it's called to early. And a setTimeout isn't an option neither because the loading time varies from browser to browser offcourse.

If any of you guys would know a fix I would be very gratefull!

Comment: Are you sure it's *really* like that and not just the fact that it's trying to load *20MB*? In my mind, you should fix that first! (I know that's not the issue, but that's an issue which makes the site horrid.)

Comment: I know it's load is very big, and where reducing the load, trying to compress the images and such , trying to lazy load where possible. I'll try to create a proof of concept on this with a smaller load!

Comment: I think the whole thing just needs rethinking. It's foolishly large and the current concept *can't* be taken down to what the average user will call an acceptable size.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan - Yes I Know this is "foolishly" large but i'm trying to reduce it where possible inside this concept. Won't be changing it soon though! Can somebody please give me a decent answer on fixing this bug with bg-images?!

Comment: @stijnd: You might have better luck getting an answer if you made a simple [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) test case that reproduces the problem. Nobody wants to wade through a complicated site when debugging :)

Answer (score 4):

## *25.5MB* is **freaking insane**.

It is truly ridiculous. You need to reduce that number, drastically.

- Use Firefox + Firebug + the [Net Panel](http://getfirebug.com/network) to profile the loading time of your site.
- In addition, use the [Page Speed extension](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/download.html#extension-rel-ff).

Some tips:

- Reduce the quality level for all `.jpg`s as much as you can bear.
- You're loading somewhere in the region of **240 `.jpg` images** that are `415*385px` - but you're only showing them at a size of `148*137px` on the actual page. You should make properly sized thumbnails for each and every one of those images.

Comment: This is a project I took over. I've been working on it today, and were looking into different methods of reducing the load. We'll see were it takes us. Thx for the Page Speed extensions - nice plugin!

Comment: Ah sorry for sounding so harsh, I didn't read what you wrote very well. I thought *you'd* made the site, I see now that's not the case. Lazy loading will definitely help, especially on the thumbnails that are only accessible by pressing a `>` button.

Comment: I've just scaled for thumbs and the load is reduced to 7.2Mb => quite the improvement. Do you know any good lazy-loading plugin? De old-ones  didn't work anymore(or so I read somewhere) There is however one that uses data-href="/global/images/sample1.jpg" but you would have to add <noscript> tags everywhere :s

I must say, even though I reduced the load the original problem still exists! BG images still won't load untill I scroll :s

Comment: Google turned up this: http://www.sebastianoarmelibattana.com/projects/jail. I haven't used it, but it looks good [and active](https://github.com/sebarmeli/JAIL).

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready() fires when the DOM is loaded. It's occurring in Chrome 13 on the dev channel, so it's something that will be an issue for you in the longer term.

It's possibly down to the massive page size. I would not normally stop to load a single page for two minutes; being a developer I am more patient than most.

This comment from the jQuery form may help you though:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/document-ready-and-window-onload-difference#14737000001123094

Answer (score 0):

`onload` doesn't fire for background images so what I suggest is add an img tag like this to the top of your page:

```
<img onload="setBackground()" src="bg.jpg" style="display:none" />
```

then in setBackground() do something like this:

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url( bg.jpg )';
```